# RestKit Core Data 'managedObjectStore is nil'

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I don't know if this is the root cause of my issue or not, but when making my request using

```
appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:path parameters:nil
```

it does some work, and when trying to map the response gives me this warning:

```
W restkit:RKObjectManager.m:635 Asked to create an `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` object, but managedObjectStore is nil.
```

followed by:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Container'
```

I assume that this is because it is not matching my request against a Managed Object Mapping, but I can't figure out why.  I am creating a persistent store using this code:

```
// Initialize managed object store
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
BOOL success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);
if (! success) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
}
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
if (! persistentStore) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
}
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
```

The appropriate mapping/response descriptor:

```
RKEntityMapping *containerMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Container" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[containerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"id" : @"containerId",
                                                  @"name" : @"name",
                                                  @"public" : @"isPublic",
                                                  @"user": @"userId",
                                                  }];
containerMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"containerId"];

responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor 
    responseDescriptorWithMapping:containerMapping
    method:RKRequestMethodAny
    pathPattern:nil 
    keyPath:@"containers"
    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Comment: Your response descriptor should have a path pattern set. What class type do you get back from `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject`?

Comment: I sideload a lot of items, so it could come from many different paths (e.g. from /containers, or from /users as a result of sideloading a list of their containers).

Comment: Do you load any paths for which that response descriptor is not valid? Have you given the object manager a reference to the managed object store?

Comment: "Have you given the object manager a reference to the managed object store?" - This was my first thought too, since none of the examples I have found show how to do that.  I wondered how it would know where the object store was.  How do I do that?

Comment: (facepalm) - objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

Comment: However, now it appears that my RKManagedObjectRequestOperation never completes (during unit tests)...

Comment: Trace logging is your friend at this point in time...

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much by way of logging.  The last thing I see is D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:131 Cached property inspection for Class 'Container': 

followed by the mapping and object descriptions, which all appear to be correct.  Then nothing.

Comment: Not enough info to go on there. You'll need to post a question with the log output / breakpoint on the last reported line and poke around

Comment: I got it.  I had expected the method of testing between RKObjectRequestOperation and RKManagedObjectRequestOperation to be the same, but they definitely aren't: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Unit-Testing-with-RestKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have not configured the object manager with a reference to the managed object store. This should be done when you create the object manager:

```
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
```

without this RestKit falls back to using plain object operations for everything.

Note: If you're logging warnings you would see `Asked to create an RKManagedObjectRequestOperation object, but managedObjectStore is nil` in the log output.